# Given a list of keys, how do we find the almost complete binary search tree of that list?

Tags: data-structures, binary-search-tree

I saw an answer here with the idea implemented in Python (not very familiar with Python) - I was looking for a more general algorithm.

EDIT:

For clarification:
Say we are given a list of integer keys: 23 44 88 12 74 32 7 39 10

That list was chosen arbitrarily. We are to create an almost complete (or complete) binary search tree from that list. There is supposed to be only one such tree...how do we find it?

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking. Please edit your question and add more detail. Give us an example.

Comment: @JimMischel I edited the question. Hope its clearer now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A [binary search tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_tree) is constructed so that all items on a node's left subtree are less than the node, and all nodes on the right subtree are greater than the node.

A complete (or almost complete) binary tree is one in which all levels except possibly the last are completely full, and the bottom level is filled to the left.

So, for example, this is an almost-complete binary search tree:

```
     4
   /   \
  2     5
 / \
1   3
```

This is not:

```
     3
   /   \
  2     4
 /       \
1         5
```

Because the bottom level of the tree is not filled from the left.

If the number of items is one less than a power of two (i.e. 3, 7, 15, etc.), then building the tree is easy. Start by sorting the list. Then, take the middle element as the root. So if you have `[1,2,3,4,5,6,7]`, and the root node is 4.

You do the same thing recursively for the right and left halves of the array.

If the number of items is not one less than a power of two, you have to adjust the starting point (the root node) so that the bottom row is left-filled. Note that you might have to apply that adjustment recursively, as well, whenever your subtree length is not one less than a power of two.

Since this is a homework assignment, I'll leave that for you to figure out.

Comment: Actually, I am studying for finals...was not explained in the text unfortunately. But thank you for the answer. Well explained.